# Java PayPal Developers - How to withdraw?

Tags: java, api, paypal

I want to create a web interface in which the user can deposit money and withdraw it.

I would like to know if PayPal has an API for withdrawing. In the next link (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment) I can see how paypal provides us an API for making payments but I don't know the way for doing withdraws.

This API allows you to refund a sale, but i don't need it, I don't want to refund a sale, I need to allow users to withdraw the amount of money that they want.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "withdraw"? Like an ATM? If that's the case, really you're not supposed to provide this service (as PayPal does, and charges for it - https://www.paypal.com/webapps/helpcenter/article/?articleID=94037&m=SRE ), but if you're willing to pay the fee you should just make a payment from them to you, and describe it as "cashback" or something.

Comment: I mean, I need to make a payment to my client. My client deposite money and I want to allow them withdraw the amount that they want from his account. It's not like an ATM. For example, it is like an online gambling company, where users deposit money for gambling and then they could withdraw their profits. So, the client want to withdraw 50 USD, So I have to make a payment from my PayPal account to the Client.

Comment: Direct payments from my PayPal Account to my webapp's users credit cards or paypal accounts...